# How can I make an animated UIImage move across the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I would like to move an animated UIImage across the screen. How is this possible?

Here is my code so far with UIImage animation:

```
self.myImageWalk.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img01.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img02.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"img03.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"img04.png"], nil];

[self.myImageWalk setAnimationRepeatCount:5];
[self.myImageWalk setAnimationDuration:2];
[self.myImageWalk startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declare this function .h file

```
-(void)doAnimate:(CGRect)rect;
```

.m file

```
-(void)doAnimate:(CGRect)rect{


    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^() {


        self.myImageWalk.frame=rect;


    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        NSLog(@"animation Done");
    }];


}
```

then call wherever u want to animate

```
     [self doAnimate:CGRectMake(300, 300, self.myImageWalk.frame.size.width, self.myImageWalk.frame.size.height)];
```

here change 300,300 to ur wish to get animate to various position.

Comment: for instant help http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/conversation/do-u-want-instant-help-for-ur-question-or-r-u-new-bee-to-iphone-ipad-develop